# Find a WPF element inside DataTemplate in the code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, bar-chart

I have a data-template

```
<Window.Resources>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="BarChartItemsTemplate">
         <Border Width="385" Height="50">
            <Grid>
               <Rectangle Name="rectangleBarChart" Fill="MediumOrchid" StrokeThickness="2" Height="40" Width="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                  <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                     <ScaleTransform ScaleX="4"/>
                  </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
               </Rectangle>
               <TextBlock Margin="14" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}">
                  <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                     <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="1"/>
                     </TransformGroup>
                  </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
               </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
```

I have a button on the form. I need to change the scale(scaleTransform) the rectangle from the dataTemplate. How am I supposed to access the 'rectangleBarChart' element in the Button_Click event of the above mentioned button ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I use this function a lot in my WPF programs to find children elements:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
   if (depObj != null)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
       {
           DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

           if (child != null && child is T)
               yield return (T)child;

           foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
               yield return childOfChild;
       }
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var rectangle in FindVisualChildren<Rectangle>(this))
{
  if (rectangle.Name == "rectangleBarChart")
  {
    /*   Your code here  */
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man I am able to get into the if block after finding the element, but after changing some properties of the rectangle suppose rectangle.Fill=Brushes.Red, these changes are not reflected back.( I am using the above mentioned dataTemplate as my ItemTemplate for a ListBox) So how to update the changes to the ListBox ?

Comment: You are a saint!  This works great.  I could not get other solutions to work.

Answer (score 4):

Do *not* do it. If you need to change something in a `DataTemplate` then bind the respective properties and modify the underlying data. Also i would recommend binding the `Button.Command` to an `ICommand` on your data/view-model (see MVVM) instead of using events, then you are in the right context already and the view does not need to do anything.

Comment: @H. B. - I am using the DataTemplate as follows:
    
  <ListBox Name="barChartListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BarChartItemsTemplate}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource BarChartItemsPanel}" Margin="36,-3,48,12"></ListBox>

I am able to access the ListBox in my code-behind but I want to scale the rectangle and reflect the changes again to the UI.

For that I did:


                    rectangle.Fill = Brushes.MediumVioletRed;
                    rectangle.Height = 10;
                    rectangle.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(2, 1);

Comment: @GrowWithWPF: So what? Nothing prevents you from binding all those properties in the template and changing the bound object instead.