# Change properties of an element in DataTemplate and reflect the changes

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, scaletransform

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826272/find-a-wpf-element-inside-datatemplate-in-the-code-behind/11832860#11832860) is the question I had posted. Now, I am not able to reflect the changes made to the rectangle element in the DataTemplate. I want to scaleX the rectangle depending on some values and conditions in the code-behind. I did the following :

```
     foreach (var rectangle in FindVisualChildren<Rectangle>(this))
     {
       if (rectangle.Name == "rectangleBarChart" && isRectangle == false)
       {
             rectangle.Fill = Brushes.MediumVioletRed;
             rectangle.Height = 10;
             rectangle.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(2, 1);
             isRectangle = true;
       }
     }
```

But, the changes are not reflected, it uses the same old DataTemplate. Any hints to refelct the changes to the UI ?

Answer (score 0):

```
rectangle.Fill = Brushes.MediumVioletRed;
            rectangle.Height = 10;
            rectangle.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(2, 1);
            isRectangle = true;
            **rectangle.UpdateLayout();**
```

Use UpdateLayOut Method to update.I hope this will help.