# Find any item in treeview in WFP with UID

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a treeview in WPF and we add items programatically. I want a to add find any item using UID, that is assigned and then add additional items into it.

I tried to parse the tree but know how to handle nested items.

Is there an simpler tried and tested way that I am unaware of?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: are you trying to find an element with a specifiic "Name" ?

Comment: Yes, but it could be nested deep.

Comment: as deep as you like it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11826541/6449190

Comment: oh ho, that worked!