# How to get name of button i created in data template to use it

Tags: c#, wpf

In C# and WPF, I have a button that I created in data template. When I give a name to the button, it doesn't recognize or isn't seen at code behind to use it.

I am trying to add a button inside data template from code behind and give a name to the button but the button not seen in another block. How can I solve this? By the way I need the data template to use it.

Comment: Can you give some code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see an example implementation here:
[How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
Or here:
[Find a WPF element inside DataTemplate in the code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826272/find-a-wpf-element-inside-datatemplate-in-the-code-behind)

But I warn you right away, although it is possible to do this, I highly do not recommend doing this.
In a proper WPF implementation, you would create an object - an instance of the class that your DataTemplate is intended to represent. All UI elements in the template must be dependent on the properties of this instance. Then your task will be reduced to managing the property values of this instance, instead of solving the rather non-trivial task of searching for UI elements in the Data Template.
Moreover, if you consider that the Data Template can change independently of the Code Behind, then such an implementation will make it much easier to modernize and maintain the code.